# How to define String of characters?

Tags: string, haskell, encryption

I'm new to Haskell hope someone will help me. I need to define a data structure for a string of characters (alphabet) which will represent a substitution cipher.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, what about a list of characters, also known as a `String`

Answer (score 2):

Since this is for representing a substituition cypher

```
 type Cypher = [(Char, Char)]

  makeCypher :: String -> Cypher
  makeCypher s = zip ['a' .. 'z'] s
```

Here you just pass a string representing each new letter positionally, so "f.." will map a to f. It returns a list of pairs `[('a', 'f')...]`.

Then to use it,

```
 import Data.Maybe
 encrypt :: Cypher -> String -> String
 encrypt cyph = mapMaybe (flip lookup cyph)
```

Which just looks up each character in the list of pairs.

Another option is to use `Data.Map` which can be used almost identically to above, substituting `zip` for `fromList` and similar.

Answer (score 1):

How about a `List` of `Char`

```
Prelude> let alphabet = ['a'..'z']
Prelude> alphabet
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```